# How would I make data coming from an endpoint appear one time each instead of repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I have an array that of which contains objects at each index.  I'd like to put the colors inside a `<tr><td></td></tr>`.  With my current code below (when I `console.log(data[item].colors);`) - all of the colors repeatedly come out instead of just displaying them each one time only.  The endpoint I'm using's making this behavior intentional.

How would I make it so that each color displays one time only, including when new colors get added to the endpoint in the future?  I've tried to so many ways to tackle this but to no avail.

When I `console.log(data[item].colors);`:

```
(3) Blue
(12) Green
(5) Teal
(4) Red
Purple
(3) Blue
(12) Green
(5) Teal
(4) Red
```

My code:

```
<>
   {
      Object.keys(data).map((item,index) => {
        return <tr key={index}><td>{data[item].colors}</td></tr>
      })
   }
</>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi first Stackoverflow answer here...

I don't fully understand the question but if you want to avoid repeating words inside your `<tr></tr>` i would suggest to use a Set:

```js
// This may be your array
let colors = ["Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Teal", "Blue", "Red", "Teal"]

// Step 1
let filteredColors = new Set(colors);

// Step 2: Convert the result object to an array again
let newColors = [...filteredColors];

console.log(newColors)
// ["Blue", "Red", "Teal"]
```

Then you can map your new array as you've done before.

**EDIT**

I made this CodeSandbox with a solution if the Array has objects inside and you want to filter all values from an specific key to show them without repeating:

https://codesandbox.io/s/colors-solution-lxw6q?file=/src/App.js

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry I should've been a little more clear, it's an array objects like so: `[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: Sorry, i just read this. Maybe there's a cleaner solution but i suggest to pre-proccess your Array before mapping. I made a codesandbox with my solution https://codesandbox.io/s/colors-solution-lxw6q

Comment: Thank you man, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped you, i just edited my first anwer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the response of the api into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection.

So you can create a new Set, then loop over the colors and add them to the Set without worrying about duplicates:

```
const colors = new Set();
data[item].colors.forEach(color => colors.add(color));
```

You can iterate over a set with the `values` or `entries` method or you convert it to an array like this `[...colors]` or like this `Array.from(colors)` and use the normal array methods.